# Какой из следующих фрагментов действителен?

Tags: c

```
char f{ return __func__[0]; }
 
void f{ return __func__; }
 
double f{ return __func__; }
 
char f{ return __func__; }
```

Comment: Да пожалуй что никакой... Инициализировать переменную с помощью `return`...

Comment: тесты по cisco,куча ошибок

Comment: Если бы были скобки - то корректным было бы `char f(){ return __func__[0]; }`

Comment: `const char *f() { return __func__; }`